# Dual monitors, DVI-I to VGA converter resolution resolving broken

Tags: nvidia, multi-monitor, manjaro, resolution

Generally I just moved to latest Manjaro with Xfce. My graphics card is GeForce 660 Ti (from Gigabyte). I have 2 monitors plugged in, one (primary) is full-hd screen that I got plugged to HDMI port, external monitor is old LCD with VGA only, so I had to get converter to plug it in to my graphics card. The converter is DVI-I to VGA.

Everything works just fine when I am running default linux drivers, but I need non-free Nvidia drivers and here comes the problem...
Once I booted into the system after drivers installation I figured out that my external display is in 640x480, I attempted to fix this by using GUI tool but it was the highest possible option. Then I tried using xrandr but running (with creating mode first ofc):

```
xrandr --addmode DVI-I-0 "1024x768_60.00"
```

Results in:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  41
  Current serial number in output stream:  42
```

I tried nvidia-settings but it doesn't let me to set this resolution too. I've tried to setup everything there but resolution and save it as x config in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d named 90-monitor.confg (as found in a few forums). I restared X server, then entire machine but it didn't change anything.

First I was trying to set max supported resolution (1280x1024) but I thought that might be a problem so I try to set at least 1024x768.

I bet this problem comes from this converter as it interrupts display properties resolving (screen size in this case). However converter is not a barrier itself as I said before - resolution was fine with noveau drivers

```
    DVI-I-0 connected 640x480+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   640x480       59.94*+
   320x240       60.05
```

As you can see there, it tells me screen is 0x0mm.

I am a moderate linux user, much time spent on Linux but my knowledge is still little, so please help me with simple instructions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found some instructions that worked (almost) fine.

https://web.archive.org/web/20171024001521/https://sammart.in/2012/05/29/enabling-resolutions-in-ubuntu-12-04-lubuntu-12-04/

Followed everything exactly as it is there, I tried to set 1280x1024 (max for this LCD monitor), rebooted and it **was like that while in login-screen**! Once I logged in resolution changed back to 640x480 (I thought to myself *OH COME ON YOU STUPID F****), but I decided to check GUI tool to see available resolutions and I found that there is 1024x768 available, clicked apply and it works fine now.

Comment: I love that this answer came with a story.

Comment: This worked!  Thanks!  I had the exact same experience with the login screen that you described.

Comment: The link has gone dead. This is why we don't generally accept link-only answers, which this is an example of.

Comment: The comment above is right, I was able to find that blog in wayback and replaced the broken link with that link.